# grep everything from a date and stop at a date

Tags: linux, grep

I would like to grep everything starts of a date till the end of the date. This is my current code

```
for z in *.log; do cat /test/data/$z | grep "`date --date="yesterday" +%m\/\%d\/\%y`" > /data/demo.log; done
```

The problem with my code is it will not grep new line for example

original data

```
   > [12/28/13 17:57:15.702]: start
   > test_miss
   > [12/28/13 17:57:15.702]: end 
   > [12/29/13 17:57:15.702]: new day
```

after grep

```
   > [12/28/13 17:57:15.702]: start
   > [12/28/13 17:57:15.702]: end
```

Desired output

```
   > [12/28/13 17:57:15.702]: start
   > test_miss
   > [12/28/13 17:57:15.702]: end
```

How can i get everything from the start of my date till the end of my date, thanks inadvance

Comment: Use [gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) not `grep`

Comment: gawk will grep everything including today's info I would only like to grab only yesterday info

Comment: no, `gawk` has (global) variables to handle state.

Comment: you can use the **-A n** switch of Grep. it will print n number of lines after the match.

Comment: @Anubhab what i really want is the Desired output not printing number of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for all the help and tips anyway this is what i did

```
for z in *.log; 
do
yest=$(grep -n "$( date --date="yesterday" +%m\/\%d\/\%y )" /data/log/$z |cut -f1 -d: | head -n 1) ;
today=$(grep -n "$( date --date="today" +%m\/\%d\/\%y )" /data/log/$z |cut -f1 -d: | head -n 1) ;

if [[ -z "$today" ]]
then
awk "NR>="$yest"" "/data/log/$z" > /data/test/$z;

else
today=$(($today - 1)) ; 
awk "NR>="$yest"&&NR<=$today" "/data/log/$z" > /data/test/$z;
fi
done
```

i use grep to search for the first and last line number and use awk to capture everything in it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [gawk](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/) like e.g.

```
 yest=$(date --date="yesterday" +%m\/\%d\/\%y`")
 for z in *.log; do
   awk "/$yest/{inside= !inside;print;next;} {if (inside) print;}" $z
 done
```

I am [using a variable](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Using-Variables.html) `inside` as a boolean flag, switched when encountering the `$yest` (yesterday's date).

Comment: I tried this and it is not working for me first error 
syntax error: unexpected end of file
i saw that the variable $yest is missing `" at the beginning, so i fix it then re-run the script
still getting all the information

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 cat logfile | awk '$0 >= "xx/xx/xx 00:00" && $0 <= "yy/yy/yy 00:00"'
```

or

```
 cat /var/log/messages | awk '$0 >= "Dec 30 14:45:01" && $0 <= "Dec 30 14:50:01"'


NOTE - The timestamps are at the beginning of each line and you need to include the correct 
timestamp format.
```

Comment: $0 in awk means the whole record. isnt it? are you sure this will work?

Comment: Good except for the [Useless use of `cat`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cat_%28Unix%29#Useless_use_of_cat); and `$0` should be `$1`

Comment: assumption - the timestamps are at the beginning of each line, this is $0

Comment: @TharangaAbeyseela: no, the first field for `awk` is `$1`

Comment: $0 is whole line. sorry for my previous comment. it is misunderstanding.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but for my current issue not all line start with a timestamp check my original data

Comment: @Anubhab $0 is the whole line. i was trying this on my /var/log/message. it worked.

Comment: i know that. that what my concern is. I really don't understand how are you checking the whole line to be a timestamp

Comment: that is why you use the pattern to check with >=  && <=, try that on your log file. use correct timestamp format. you will find it :)